# find whether a string is present directly or indirectly in all files

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have set of c files and I need to find out whether a particular header file is directly or indirectly present in all the files.

```
For ex:-
Header files:-

hf1.h:-
int i = 10;

hf2.h:-
#include "hf1.h"

hf3.h:-
#include <hf1.h>

hf4.h:-
#include <hf3.h>

c files:-
cf1.c:-
#include <hf1.h>

cf2.c:-
#include <hf2.h>

cf3.c:-
#include <hf4.h>
```

In this case hf4.h indirectly included hf1.h file. I need to find our whether hf1.h is directly or indircetly included in all the files. Let me know if anyone need more clarification.

Any unix commands or shell scripts to solve this problem.

Comment: i think that you may rename the header file and compile the source. it will list you the list of files using it as an error message. just grep and apply sort and list the unique files

Comment: @John The problem in this approach is that, as soon as compiler find this error in one file, compilation terminates.s

Comment: ok. then add a strangely named variable declaration in the header file and preprocess it(with -E option in gcc) and then grep the given strange name. i guess that grep has an option to list the filename alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have cases of code like

```
#include               <hf1.h>
#include \
<hf1.h>
```

then finding the direct includes is a simple

```
grep -l '#include .hf1\.h'
```

command. For finding the indirect includes I suggest that you put

```
#error "hf1_included"
```

into hf1.h and compile all files (e.g. "make -k" or similar). Capture stderr and search for hf1_included. This will give a list of files that either directly or indirectly includes hf1.h. Now you can extract a list of only indirect includes by also taking into account the first list of only direct includes. You can use the program `comm` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Introduce a #error directive into hf1.h
2. `make clean`
3. `make -k all`
4. All object files that now exist have not included hf1.h

The `-k` step is the crucial one: It ensures that compilation continues past the first broken file.

Answer (score 1):

A long way would be to use the -E option in gcc (with this parameter it actually gives the output after pre-processing only, no compilation is done) for all the c files and then search for parts of each header files in all the outputs. 
Will update if any shorter method comes to mind.